# Sentry: how to search for issues resolved in the last week

Tags: sentry

I'm trying to gather weekly statistics from [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/), using the [search feature](https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/search/).

I want to find new errors in the last week. Which I think I can do with `age`:

```
is:unresolved age:-1w
```

But how do I search for issues that were resolved in the last week? I can't find any search tag for this. I can't even find a resolved timestamp anywhere when viewing an individual issue.